# Explanation of SBB instruction

Tags: assembly

I have this Asm from a book that suppose to do a Boolean cast: `rax := rax ? 1 : 0`

```
1. neg      rax
2. sbb      rax,rax
3. neg      rax
```

But as i understand this code and the instructions (below), this would work
only if the register will have 0 in it.

because lets assume that (register have some positive number in it):

```
rax = 9    ;initial register
rax = -9   ;after line 1
rax = -17  ;after line 2
rax = 17   ;after line 3
```

register have 0 in it:

```
rax = 0    ;initial register
rax = 0    ;after line 1
rax = 0    ;after line 2
rax = 0    ;after line 3
```

I think that the author meant to do `add` in line 2 instead of `sbb` am i correct?

> Instruction explanations: 
>   neg instruction:
>
> ```
> neg Destination      ;Destination = -Destination      
> if(Destination == 0)
>   CF = 0;
> else 
>   CF = 1;
> ```
>
> sbb instruction:
>
> ```
> sbb Destination, Source      ;Destination = Destination - (Source + CF);
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SBB:

> Destination = Destination - (Source + CF);

```
-9 - ( -9 + 1 ) = -9 - ( -8 ) = -9 + 8 = -1, not -17
```

Comment: @Oh you right, so embarrassing